# Create failed for Availability Group 'AGN'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, availability-groups

I tried creating availability group (AOH) many times but no luck , It got failed every time. Please help me on this case.

I configured Windows cluster (Name as 'WINCLUSTER') with two nodes. They are
1. Node1
2. Node2

in that I configured SQL server cluster (Active/Active) with  two instances.
one instance named as 'HRITS\BAK' and other 'HRITS1\BAK1'.

I made sure configuration met all prerequisite and important steps before configuring AOH.

I created on database as sampledb in 'HRITS\BAK' instance in node1.
and I tried to creating Alwayson group with necessary steps.

But I am facing one error and not able to troubleshoot. Please find the below screen shot and please provide guideline for configuring it successfully.

[image: Please find error screenshot]
[image: Nodes and instance info]

Please let me know if any further details are required for resolving this issue.

Comment: Do you use 2008, 2008R2 or 2012 version?

Comment: Availability Groups only exist on SQL Server 2012 and up. I'm not sure why this is tagged with 2008.

Answer (score 3):

I see you're combining Failover Cluster Instances (FCIs) and Database Availability Groups. That's fine, except that the installer won't allow you to set up an availability group on failover cluster instances that can be owned by the same servers, just like the error message says. In other words, the set of servers that can run HRITS\BAK can't overlap with the set of servers that can run HRITS\BAK1.

An availability group doesn't give you much additional fault tolerance in the scenario you described because if Node1 or NODE2 failed, both failover cluster instances would be running on the same server.

To get around the error, you could reinstall the SQL Servers as standalone instances. Alternatively, if this design is what you really want, I believe the installer might work if you change the 'possible owner' setting for resources in each cluster group. This is possible with Powershell, for example:

```
Get-ClusterGroup -Name "SQL Server (BAK)"|Get-ClusterResource|Set-ClusterOwnerNode -Owners NODE2
Get-ClusterGroup -Name "SQL Server (BAK1)"|Get-ClusterResource|Set-ClusterOwnerNode -Owners node1
```

That said, this design might not make any sense for the aforementioned reasons unless it's just for a lab.